# Integrating layer-WebSDK in Cordova applications

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I want to use layer service in my ionic app,

https://github.com/layerhq/layer-websdk

I tried all three ways there: NPM, CDN, Source;

But I still cannot call layer.Client successfully in my ionic app.

[image]

Please give some advice.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried other mobile chatting sdks? 
[GetSocial](http://www.getsocial.im) also has full Cordova support.

link: http://docs.getsocial.im/#adding-getsocial-to-your-app